# JavaScript loop through all existing objects to find an object key

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to debug a system that was built by someone else. I have a minified library that makes an ajax (xhr) call to an external data source and writes the received data to an object or a variable. The call is made immediately after page load so I can't catch it by appending a function to register all XHR call requests. So I am trying to run a loop through all variables and objects that the browser window has. I am trying this:

```js
var foundVar = false;
loopThroughObject(this);

function loopThroughObject(obj) {
  if (!foundVar) {
    try {
      for (var name in obj) {
        if (obj[name] && {}.toString.call(obj[name]) === '[object Function]') { //making sure that the object is not a function 
        } else {
          if (name == 'searchedKey') { //found the object with key = searchedKey
            console.log(obj[name]);
            foundVar = true;
          } else {
            setTimeout(loopThroughObject.bind(null, obj[name]), 10); //do more recursion of inner objects
          }
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {}
  }
}
```

The problem is that the `setTimeout(loopThroughObject.bind(null, obj[name]), 0);` part stacks up and a memory issue occurs. I tried the simple `loopThroughObject(obj[name])`, but I am facing the "Too much recursion" error after 25000 loops. It also seems that I am missing something and it causes the loop go through some object types that I don't need. Does anyone know a more efficient way to do that loop?

P.S. I tried a very simple HTML page and the code works fine:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    var test = JSON.parse("{\"searchedKey\":\"12\"}");
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"The call is made immediately after page load so I can't catch it by appending a function to register all XHR call requests."* You could add your script to do that **before** the other script. If you have control over the page source, you can always control the order of things.

Comment: The thing is that I don't have access to the source. Client lost the access to server after the developer disappeared and we are trying to recreate the system.

Comment: You have access to the server, right? So you can change the HTML. Also, beware that not everything is reachable from `window`, the data you're looking for may well be in a variable in a function somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is almost certainly the fact that `window` has several properties that point back to itself, so your code is going into an infinite loop. There may well be other circular references.

You can remember what objects you've already looked in using a `Set`, like this (I've also added a few other tweaks; for instance, you can check for a function with `typeof x === "function"`):

```
let foundVar = false;
let seen = new Set();
loopThroughObject(this);

function loopThroughObject(obj) {
    if (!foundVar) {
        try {
            for (const name in obj) {
                const value = obj[name];
                if (typeof value !== "function") {
                    if (name == "searchedKey") { // found the object with key = searchedKey
                        console.log(value);
                        foundVar = true;
                        break;
                    } else if (value && typeof value === "object" && !seen.has(value)) {
                        seen.add(value);
                        loopThroughObject(value); // No need for setTimeout
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (error) {}
    }
}
```